# Anatomically Correct European Dragon

Tags: internal-consistency, evolution, creature-design, mythical-creatures

In the modern period, the European dragon is typically depicted as a huge, fire-breathing, scaly, horned, lizard-like creature; the creature also has leathery, bat-like wings, four legs, and a long, muscular prehensile tail. Is there a realistic way that it could evolve?

Using earth or near earth biology how close could I get to the classic [European Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_dragon)? Is there a reason that a European Dragon couldn't evolve?